# Why does my flow create multiple items when I upload a new document to a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

For some unknown reason whenever I upload a new document to the document library, my background flow pulls the required data correctly but it creates multiple new items when it's only meant to create one in the list.

It seems to create as many new items in the list as there are files in the SharePoint library.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

Screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Get files (properties only)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#get-files-properties-only) action which retrieves all files in mentioned library/folder. Then you are applying loop on **all results/files** >> This is the reason flow is creating multiple items for each file in folder/library.

---

If you are trying to get the properties of newly uploaded file, you should directly use "List rows present in a table" action in Power Automate like:

[image]

You need to pass the file `Identifier` from trigger to this action to limit the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. So I should remove the "Get files (properties only)" item in the flow? I configured 'varIdentifier' to encourage dynamic file name recognition. Can I still use that in "list rows..." for the file? Or does it have to be SharePoint 'Identifier'?

Comment: First of all, are you trying to get the rows from only one file (for which flow is running), right? If Yes, you can remove "Get files" action.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the rows from one table in an excel file. This flow is triggered every time a new file is uploaded.

Comment: No need to create new variable for passing file name dynamically to "List rows present in a table" action. You can directly use `Identifier` from trigger outputs which is also dynamic file identifier for the particular file. see image attached in my answer. Also, in this case you don't have to use first "Apply to each" loop in your flow as now you only have one file.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I made the changes you suggested, however the flow does not work now. New items aren't being created. Also, flow is automatically creating "Apply to each" items. I can't seem to stop this.

Comment: You have to use only one Apply to each loop for results from "List rows present in a table" action.

Comment: I know, but when I want to include items from the excel file and the SharePoint file name in a new "Create item" flow automatically creates multiple apply to each parameters. I can't stop that from happening.